# Set all variables in struct to zero / one

Tags: c

I would like to know if there is possible to initialize all variables (within a LOOP) present in a Struct to `0` and back to `1`.

Here is a demonstrating program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEDS_LENGTH 7

void inititate_to_zero(void);
void inititate_to_one(void);

struct pins
{
    unsigned char state : 1;
    unsigned char LED0  : 1;
    unsigned char LED1  : 1;
    unsigned char LED2  : 1;
    unsigned char LED3  : 1;
    unsigned char LED4  : 1;
    unsigned char LED5  : 1;
}pins;

int main(void)
{
    inititate_to_zero( );
    inititate_to_one( );
}

void inititate_to_zero(void)
{
    for(unsigned char i = 0; i < LEDS_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        /// set all variable in struct pins to 0;
        pins.VARIABLE[SOME_HOW] ^= ( 1 << 0 );
    }
}

void inititate_to_one(void)
{
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < LEDS_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        /// set all variable in struct pins to 1;
        pins.VARIABLE[SOME_HOW] ^= ( 1 << 0 );
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I needed to replace the function `inititate_to_one()`  to use a LOOP if it is possible:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEDS_LENGTH 7

void inititate_to_one ( void );

struct pins
{
    volatile unsigned char state    : 1;
    unsigned char LED0              : 1;
    unsigned char LED1              : 1;
    unsigned char LED2              : 1;
    unsigned char LED3              : 1;
    unsigned char LED4              : 1;
    unsigned char LED5              : 1;
}pins{ 0 };


int main( void )
{
    inititate_to_one ( );
}

void inititate_to_one( void )
{
    state ^= ( 1 << 0 );
    LED0  ^= ( 1 << 0 );
    LED1  ^= ( 1 << 0 );
    LED2  ^= ( 1 << 0 );
    LED3  ^= ( 1 << 0 );
    LED4  ^= ( 1 << 0 );
    LED5  ^= ( 1 << 0 );
}
```

Comment: Perhaps what you really want is an array? Or possibly single `unsigned char` used as a bit-field?

Comment: *Initialization* to 0 (or any zero-ish/null value) for a C struct is straightforward. *Setting* to 0 or 1 later, or initialization to 1, is different. So it really depends on what question your asking *precisely*.

Comment: how about making an array of LED[i] instead of led0 led1...

Comment: You have `memset` available right? (e.g. `memset (&pins, 1, sizeof (struct pins));`) and just use `0` to zero each byte.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Your suggestion looks interesting. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: `Perhaps what you really want is an array?` perhaps uCs does not have unlimited resources

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I was thinking on that too, but I was not sure is better that what I was asking.

Comment: have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2000646/7177029) ?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin this memset will not work. instead of 1 you need 0xff

Comment: PORTB on `atmega328` has `0` to `5` so my intention is to save space as much as possible. So I tough that probably `const unsigned char LEDS[] = { PB0, PB1, PB2, PB3, PB4, PB5 };` needs more space that a struct with bit-field.

Comment: @P__J__ - Thank you -- good catch, yes `memset (&pins, 0xff, sizeof (struct pins));`

Comment: I added in the loop an example of what exactly I need to do.

Comment: What do you mean by ".. back to `1`" - they were never `1` to go "back to".  The initialisation to zero can be achieved in the declaration by `... } pins = {0} ;`

Comment: @Clifford Thank you for your suggestion. You are all most there. Please check the EDIT part now.

Comment: I recommend that you don't use bit-fields. Instead use simple unsigned integer, and bitwise operations to adjust individual bits. Changing all bits will be simple assignment.

Comment: `LED5  ^= ( 1 << 0 );` only sets the bit to 1 if it is not already 1.  It flips the bit which is not what the function name suggests.  Why not simply `LED5 = 1`?  The XOR is wrong, and the shift pointless. Moreover you have not answered by question - your question remains unclear.

Comment: The main goal was [to replaces the array in my example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54331621/setting-up-interrupts-on-atmega328-in-pure-c/54331887?noredirect=1#comment95482353_54331887) with bit-fields.

Comment: @Clifford I think (hope) that the EDIT part does explain it better.

Comment: @JohnDoe : Note really, and your insistence that the answer use a loop is an unnecessary constraint.  `memset()` will work as already advised.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

having

```
struct pins
{
    volatile unsigned char state    : 1;
    unsigned char LED0              : 1;
    unsigned char LED1              : 1;
    unsigned char LED2              : 1;
    unsigned char LED3              : 1;
    unsigned char LED4              : 1;
    unsigned char LED5              : 1;
}pins;
```

to set all to 0 : `memset(&pins, 0, sizeof(pins));`

to set all to 1 : `memset(&pins, -1, sizeof(pins));`

and probably the memset will be optimize to just set one byte

---

To help John Doe :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct pins
{
    volatile unsigned char state    : 1;
    unsigned char LED0              : 1;
    unsigned char LED1              : 1;
    unsigned char LED2              : 1;
    unsigned char LED3              : 1;
    unsigned char LED4              : 1;
    unsigned char LED5              : 1;
} pins;

void pr()
{
  printf("%u %u %u %u %u %u %u\n",
     pins.state, pins.LED0, pins.LED1, pins.LED2, pins.LED3, pins.LED4, pins.LED5);
}

int main()
{
  /* pins is already to 0 because static */
  memset(&pins, -1, sizeof(pins));
  pr();
  memset(&pins, 0, sizeof(pins));
  pr();
  memset(&pins, -1, sizeof(pins));
  pr();

  return 0;
}
```

Execution :

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: And that value 255, where does it come from?

Comment: @Dominique 255 has all its bits to 1, 0xff in hexadecimal and 11111111 in binary

Comment: Not all bits. if a byte has `8` bit: then `0` means `0000 0000` and what i need for one is `0000 0001` for all variables. Think of this: `uint8_t led = 0:` this means `0000 0000` then if I do `led ^= ( 1 << 0 );` I get `0000 0001` and this is what I need.

Comment: I need to set all to `0000 0000` and `0000 0001`. Because I use Bit-field, I have only on bit, so this BIT should be `0` and `1`

Comment: @Dominique I edited to use -1 to be compatible with any size of byte up to an int (even that is stupid of course)

Comment: `and probably the memset will be optimize to just set one byte` I need only one BIT not the whole BYTE

Comment: @JohnDoe you request to set state and all the LEDi to 0 or 1 no ? This what I do

Comment: When I use this: `memset(&pins, 0, sizeof(pins));` then the variables are `0000 0000` and when I use this: `memset(&pins, -1, sizeof(pins));` then tha variables becomes `1111 1111` am I right? If so, then is wrong. I need to be `0000 0000` and `0000 0001`. But I think that is not possible.

Comment: @Dominique You are right. I do not need `255`. What  I need is that  `0` to become `1` and not `255`.

Comment: @JohnDoe I edited my answer to put a full programm and execution

Comment: @JohnDoe: Each one of your fields is a single bit in length (and most likely shares storage with the other fields). Setting the entire structure to be all 1s is equivalent to your function. I'd usually use `~0` (i.e. NOT 0) instead of `-1` for clarity though.

Comment: No, that is not what I need. I do not need `1 1 1 1 1 1 1` I need `0000 0001` Please read my EDITED Question.

Comment: @JohnDoe : You have not understood this answer; by setting all _bytes_ occupied by the structure to all ones, the single bit-fields will implicitly become `1` because they are _packed_ into those _bytes_.  You could just try it.  Note that I's suggest `~0` rather then `-1`, but either will work.

Comment: @Clifford Oh I did not understand that indeed . Sorry Guys. :D